# Compile KTechlab in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: kubuntu, compiling, kde4

I couldn't find a package from KTechlab. I decided to compile it from the sources but I have a problem that I can't seem to solve. https://github.com/ktechlab/ktechlab-0.3

```
$ cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
qmake: could not exec '/usr/lib/qt5/bin/qmake': No such file or directory
-- Looking for Q_WS_X11
-- Looking for Q_WS_X11 - found
-- Looking for Q_WS_WIN
-- Looking for Q_WS_WIN - not found
-- Looking for Q_WS_QWS
-- Looking for Q_WS_QWS - not found
-- Looking for Q_WS_MAC
-- Looking for Q_WS_MAC - not found
-- Found Qt4: /usr/bin/qmake-qt4 (found suitable version "4.8.7", minimum required is "4.6.0") 
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindKDE4.cmake:61 (message):
  ERROR: Could not find KDE4 kde4-config
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:11 (find_package)
```

I searched but could not install kdelibs4...

Here is my configuration:

- Ubuntu 20.04
- I installed Kde desktop: sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop

Can you help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that ktechlab-0.3 is very old branch, it relies on Qt4 which is not available for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS via official repositories.

But you can install it using alternative repository - KDE Trinity R14 with:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/j/jasper/libjasper1_1.900.1-debian1-2.4ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./libjasper1_1.900.1-debian1-2.4ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb

sudo add-apt-repository "deb https://ftp.fau.de/trinity/trinity-r14.0.0/ubuntu/ focal main"
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys C93AF1698685AD8B
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install ktechlab-trinity
```

This will end with installation of KTechlab 0.3 as you have requested in the question. You can it using commandline `/opt/trinity/bin/ktechlab` and you will get the following:

[image: KTechLab 0.3 from KDE Trinity R14]

---

I would recommend to switch to modern 0.50.1 version and compile it by translating [ArchLinux AUR PKGBUILD](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=ktechlab) to the deb-package names as follows:

```
sudo apt install build-essential git cmake gfortran fftw3-dev qtbase5-dev qttools5-dev libqt5serialport5-dev qtmultimedia5-dev libqt5multimedia5-plugins libqt5sql5-sqlite autoconf automake libtool texinfo libusb-1.0-0-dev libudev-dev

cd ~/Downloads
git clone https://github.com/ktechlab/ktechlab.git
cd ktechlab
sh build-simple.sh
sh run-simple.sh
```

and you will get the following:

[image: KTechLab 0.50.1 compiled from source code]

Note: the [`ktechlab` package is now available for 21.04 release](https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/ktechlab) from *universe* pocket, so installation is simple as `sudo add-apt-repository universe && sudo apt-get install ktechlab` .

Comment: I get error with script line 'sh build-simple.sh' (Ubuntu 20.04). 
```
CMake Error at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake:28 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5SerialPort"
  with any of the following names:

    Qt5SerialPortConfig.cmake
    qt5serialport-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5SerialPort" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Qt5SerialPort_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "Qt5SerialPort" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.
```

Comment: (re above) The fix was to run the following line with probably many unnecessary packages, but IWFM 
'sudo apt install build-essential git cmake gfortran fftw3-dev qtbase5-dev qttools5-dev libqt5serialport5-dev  qtmultimedia5-dev libqt5multimedia5-plugins libqt5sql5-sqlite autoconf automake libtool texinfo libusb-1.0-0-dev libudev-dev'

Comment: Thanks for update!